# Why is the lazy loading re-positioning the background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

I'm implementing lazy loading on my website but for some reason, when the image is fully loaded and made visible, the image position changes.

I have tried rearranging where my js and css files are called but had no luck.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3q01ha5/3/

1. This is *without* lazy loading and where i *want* the background position to be:

```
.right-image{
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511910849309-0dffb8785146?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}
```

2. This is *with* lazy loading but notice that it links to the same image but the background position is changed when fully loaded:

```
.right-image
{
  background: url("https://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
}

.right-image.visible {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511910849309-0dffb8785146?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}
```

I have attached the jsfiddle but please note I couldn't get the lazy load to function on this website but works fine locally.

I expect the background image to load in the same location regardless if I use the lazy loader. Any guidance means a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake. I was not applying the background-position to my right-image.visible css. Thank you